# Angular 2 save all changes from grid

Tags: html, angular

I need to save all changes from editable fields in table.

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let a of arr; let i = index">
      <td contenteditable>{{a.text}}</td>
      <td contenteditable type="number" pattern="[0-9]">{{a.number}}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
    <button class="btn btn-success" (click) = "saveAllChanges()">Save all </button>
```

--

```
saveAllChanges(){
    for(let a of this.arr){
      this.myservice.updateRepeat(r)
    }
}
```

Objects in array arent saved after edit on grid so it doesnt work.
Any idea how can i save all changes?